# Pivot Tree using t-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Input :
We have hierarchy data in table

The desired output :

for each leaf node, we want all her parents in the same row
Each parent in different column; one for the node code and one for node name

I know that i will use CTE and Dynamic PIVOT, but i still searching

thanks for helping,

```
use [master]
go

if object_id('tempdb..#hierarchy') is not null drop table #hierarchy

create table #hierarchy (
    hierarchy_NodeId nvarchar(256) null
    ,hierarchy_NodeName nvarchar(256) null
    ,hierarchy_ParentId nvarchar(256) null
    ,hierarchy_ParentName nvarchar(1024) null
    ,hierarchy_IsLeaf nvarchar(256) null
    ,hierarchy_level int null
    )
go

insert #hierarchy (hierarchy_NodeId, hierarchy_NodeName, hierarchy_ParentId, hierarchy_ParentName, hierarchy_IsLeaf, hierarchy_level) 
values 
 ('10', 'Hardware', NULL, NULL, 'false', 0)
,('1003', 'Printers & Scanners', '10', 'Hardware', 'false', 1)
,('1005', 'Networking', '10', 'Hardware', 'false', 1)
,('1006', 'Components & Accessories', '10', 'Hardware', 'false', 1)
,('100602', 'Cables', '1006', 'Components & Accessories', 'false', 2)
,('100606', 'Controller Cards', '1006', 'Components & Accessories', 'false', 2)
,('10060601', 'Network Adapters', '100606', 'Controller Cards', 'true', 3)
,('10060602', 'USB Controllers', '100606', 'Controller Cards', 'true', 3)
,('10060209', 'Phone/Modem Cables', '100602', 'Cables', 'true', 3)
,('100502', 'Hubs & Switches', '1005', 'Networking', 'false', 2)
,('100503', 'Network Adapters', '1005', 'Networking', 'false', 2)
,('100507', 'Wireless', '1005', 'Networking', 'false', 2)
,('100509', 'Network Cabling', '1005', 'Networking', 'false', 2)
,('10050901', 'Twisted Pair Cables', '100509', 'Network Cabling', 'false', 3)
,('10050902', 'Coaxial Cables', '100509', 'Network Cabling', 'true', 3)
,('10050903', 'Fiber Cables', '100509', 'Network Cabling', 'false', 3)
,('10050904', 'Patch Cables', '100509', 'Network Cabling', 'true', 3)
,('10050908', 'Special Network Cables', '100509', 'Network Cabling', 'true', 3)
,('10050909', 'Network Cabling Accessories', '100509', 'Network Cabling', 'true', 3)
,('1005090301', 'Multimode Fiber Cables', '10050903', 'Fiber Cables', 'true', 4)
,('1005090302', 'Singlemode Fiber Cables', '10050903', 'Fiber Cables', 'true', 4)
,('1005090102', 'Cat 5e Cables', '10050901', 'Twisted Pair Cables', 'true', 4)
,('1005090103', 'Cat 6 Cables', '10050901', 'Twisted Pair Cables', 'true', 4)
,('1005090104', 'Cat 6a Cables', '10050901', 'Twisted Pair Cables', 'true', 4)
,('10050701', 'Wireless NICs', '100507', 'Wireless', 'true', 3)
,('10050301', 'PCI Network Adapters', '100503', 'Network Adapters', 'true', 3)
,('10050302', 'PCI-E Network Adapters', '100503', 'Network Adapters', 'true', 3)
,('10050305', 'USB Network Adapters', '100503', 'Network Adapters', 'true', 3)
,('10050306', 'Wired Network Adapters', '100503', 'Network Adapters', 'true', 3)
,('10050308', '10/100 Network Adapters', '100503', 'Network Adapters', 'true', 3)
,('10050309', 'Gigabit Network Adapters', '100503', 'Network Adapters', 'true', 3)
,('10050208', 'Switch Expansion Modules', '100502', 'Hubs & Switches', 'true', 3)
,('100305', 'Print Servers', '1003', 'Printers & Scanners', 'false', 2)
,('10030501', 'Wireless Print Servers', '100305', 'Print Servers', 'true', 3)
,('10030502', 'Ethernet Print Servers', '100305', 'Print Servers', 'true', 3)
;
```

Comment: This is actually two questions: recursion and pivot. Could you please split your question?

Comment: Is there a fixed depth to the hierarchy or do the Node_IDs just get longer and longer?

Comment: Begin first using pivot :)

Comment: Can you send a sample of the desired result ?

Comment: @user3540780 : it not desired result

Comment: @user3540780
we have max 8 level, but it can be more
your solution is not the desired output

Comment: @Mohammed : this one line of the desired output
Node_id Node_Name Level_Id01 Level_Name01 Level_Id02 Level_Name02 Level_Id03 Level_Name03 Level_Id04 Level_Name04 Level_Id05 Level_Name05
1005090302 Singlemode Fiber Cables' 10 Hardware 1005 Networking 100509 Network Cabling 10050903 Fiber Cables 1005090302 Singlemode Fiber Cables

Comment: Hi all you need to do is follow the same idea to add the missing parent node ids

Comment: how devote my question ?
it serious one, it's matter to have leaf and all his parent in the same lines

Comment: 10 Hardware 1005 Networking 100509 Network Cabling 10050903 Fiber Cables 1005090302 Singlemode Fiber Cables is this what you are after as there seemed to be a lot of duplication in your previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

I think this gives you the answer you require. You could of course dynamically construct the CTE to cater for unknown depth.

```
with Parents (IDa, Pa, IDb, Pb, IDc, Pc, IDd, Pd, hierarchy_NodeId, hierarchy_NodeName, hierarchy_ParentId) as
(
    select Cast('' as varchar(50)) as IDa, Cast('' as varchar(50)) as Pa, 
    Cast('' as varchar(50)) as IDb, Cast('' as varchar(50)) as Pb, 
    Cast('' as varchar(50)) as IDc, Cast('' as varchar(50)) as Pc, 
    Cast('' as varchar(50)) as IDd, Cast('' as varchar(50)) as Pd, hierarchy_NodeId, hierarchy_NodeName, hierarchy_ParentId
    from #hierarchy
    where hierarchy_IsLeaf = 'true'
    union All
    select 
    Cast(Case when H.hierarchy_level = 0 then H.hierarchy_NodeId else e.IDa end as varchar(50)) as IDa,
    Cast(Case when H.hierarchy_level = 0 then H.hierarchy_NodeName else e.Pa end as varchar(50)) as Pa,
    Cast(Case when H.hierarchy_level = 1 then H.hierarchy_NodeId else e.IDb end as varchar(50)) as IDb,
    Cast(Case when H.hierarchy_level = 1 then H.hierarchy_NodeName else e.Pb end as varchar(50)) as Pb,
    Cast(Case when H.hierarchy_level = 2 then H.hierarchy_NodeId else e.IDc end as varchar(50)) as IDc,
    Cast(Case when H.hierarchy_level = 2 then H.hierarchy_NodeName else e.Pc end as varchar(50)) as Pc,
    Cast(Case when H.hierarchy_level = 3 then H.hierarchy_NodeId else e.IDc end as varchar(50)) as IDc,
    Cast(Case when H.hierarchy_level = 3 then H.hierarchy_NodeName else e.Pd end as varchar(50)) as Pd, 
    e.hierarchy_NodeId, e.hierarchy_NodeName, H.hierarchy_ParentId
    from #hierarchy H
    inner join Parents e On e.hierarchy_ParentId = H.hierarchy_NodeId
)

select *
from Parents
where Pa = 'Hardware'
;
```

Dynamic Version below

```
declare @sql as varchar(4000)
Declare @list as Varchar(100)
Declare @clausesA as Varchar(2000)
Declare @clausesB as Varchar(2000)

Set @list = ''
set @clausesA = ''
set @clausesB = ''

select Cast(hierarchy_level as varchar(50)) as Hlevel into #Levels
from #hierarchy 
Where hierarchy_level < (select Max(hierarchy_level) from #hierarchy)
group by hierarchy_level
order by hierarchy_level

select @list = @list + Case when @list = '' then '' else ', ' end + 'ID' + Hlevel + ', P' + Hlevel
from #Levels
order by HLevel

select @clausesA = @clausesA + Case when @clausesA = '' then 'Select ' else ', ' end 
+ 'Cast('''' as varchar(50)) as ID' + Hlevel + ' , Cast('''' as varchar(50)) as P' + Hlevel
from #Levels
order by HLevel

select @clausesB = @clausesB + Case when @clausesB = '' then 'Select ' else ', ' end 
+ 'Cast(Case when H.hierarchy_level = ' + HLevel + ' then H.hierarchy_NodeId else e.ID' + Hlevel
+ ' end as varchar(50)) as ID' + Hlevel
+ ', Cast(Case when H.hierarchy_level = ' + HLevel + ' then H.hierarchy_NodeName else e.P' 
+ HLevel + ' end as varchar(50)) as P' + HLevel
from #Levels
order by HLevel

select @sql = 
'with Parents (' + @list + ', hierarchy_NodeId, hierarchy_NodeName, hierarchy_ParentId) as
( '
    + @clausesA + ', hierarchy_NodeId, hierarchy_NodeName, hierarchy_ParentId
    from #hierarchy
    where hierarchy_IsLeaf = ''true''
    union All '
    + @clausesB + 
    ', e.hierarchy_NodeId, e.hierarchy_NodeName, H.hierarchy_ParentId
    from #hierarchy H
    inner join Parents e On e.hierarchy_ParentId = H.hierarchy_NodeId
)

select ' + @list + ', hierarchy_NodeId, hierarchy_NodeName
from Parents
where hierarchy_ParentId is null
;'

exec(@sql);

drop table #Levels
```

Answer (score 0):

This is solved but no names only nideid and parentids because in pivot no chance to put the text in the values:

```
declare @str1 nvarchar(max),@str2 nvarchar(max),@tblcount numeric,@str3 nvarchar(max),@level int,@pid nvarchar(max),@nodeid nvarchar(max),@maxnode nvarchar(max),@counter int,@c int,@breaker int;
with cte as (select row_number() over (order by hierarchy_NodeId) as n1,hierarchy_NodeId from hierarchy) select @tblcount = hierarchy_NodeId from cte where n1 in (select max(n1) from cte) order by n1 desc
set @breaker = (select count(*) from hierarchy)

set @c = 0;
set @counter = 0;
set @level = 0;
set @maxnode = @tblcount
set @str3 = ''

while (@tblcount is not null )
begin
set @level =  0
set @counter = @counter +1
set @str3 = @str3 + 'union select '''+convert(varchar(10),@counter) + ''' as seq,'+convert(varchar(10),@tblcount)+'as nodeid,hierarchy_NodeId,hierarchy_Nodename,''col'+convert(varchar(10),@level)+''' as levelid from hierarchy where hierarchy_NodeId = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max),@tblcount)
set @pid = (select hierarchy_ParentId  from hierarchy where hierarchy_NodeId = @tblcount)
while (@pid is not null)
begin
set @nodeid = (select hierarchy_NodeId from hierarchy where hierarchy_NodeId = @pid);
set @pid = (select hierarchy_parentid from hierarchy where hierarchy_NodeId = @nodeid);
if (@nodeid is not null)
begin
set @level = @level + 1
set @counter = @counter +1
set @str3 = @str3 + ' union select  '''+convert(varchar(10),@counter) + ''' as seq,'+convert(varchar(10),@tblcount)+'as nodeid,hierarchy_NodeId,hierarchy_Nodename,''col'+convert(varchar(10),@level)+''' as levelid from hierarchy where hierarchy_NodeId = ' + CONVERT(varchar(10),@nodeid)
end
else
break;  
end;
set @c = @c+1;
if (@c = @breaker)
break;
else
with cte as (select row_number() over (order by hierarchy_NodeId) as n1,hierarchy_NodeId from hierarchy) select @tblcount = isnull(hierarchy_NodeId,null) from cte where n1 in (select max(n1) - @c from cte) order by n1 desc

end
set @str3 = SUBSTRING(@str3,6,len(@str3))
if object_id('tempdb..#data') is not null drop table #data
create table #data (seq int,nodeid nvarchar(max) ,hierarchy_NodeId nvarchar(max),hierarchy_Nodename nvarchar(max),col nvarchar(max))
insert into #data exec(@str3)

set @str1 = (select stuff((select distinct ',['+col+']' from #data for xml path('')),1,1,''))
set @str1 = substring(@str1,8,len(@str1))
print @str1
set @str2 = '
select * from(select nodeid,col,hierarchy_NodeId from #data)as s
pivot
(
max(s.hierarchy_NodeId) for s.col in('+@str1+')
)as p
order by nodeid'
execute sp_executesql @str2
```